# How to install Hadoop on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, hadoop

I'm trying to follow this tutorial http://mysolvedproblem.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-on.html and instead of `hadoop-0.20.2.tar.gz` I downloaded the latest version which is `hadoop-0.23.6.tar.gz`. And I stuck on one step, where I have to change `hadoop-env.sh` file. The thing is I couldn't find `/conf/` folder at all. and also I couldn't find this file also.
Can I continue without making changes on this file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer for your question but if you're just starting with Hadoop I would go with 0.20 or 1.0. Why? Because 0.23.X is something like Hadoop 2.0 (or even 3.0) and it features a new MapReduce API that is not compatible with Hadoop 0.20 (Hadoop 1.0 is based on the 0.20 branch). So if you later look for Hadoop examples, most likely what you are going to find are Hadoop 0.20 examples. Just my piece of advice (I also started with 0.23 and switched back to 0.20) https://blogs.apache.org/bigtop/entry/all_you_wanted_to_know

Comment: very good advice! Thank you very much for pointing that out at the beginning )) You saved me a lot of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually create a file hadoop-env.sh in the /etc/hadoop directory.
http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2011/12/08/no-hadoop-env-sh-in-hadoop-0-23/

Answer (score 5):

For version 2.2.0 it's located at:

```
etc/hadoop/
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be at
/hadoop/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf